# Android Gmail app is breaking tables in my HTML email, but not in an almost identical email

Tags: android, html, email, gmail, html-email

This week I created a simple HTML email for a client. I have done this many times and am quite familiar with the various pitfalls and tricks to writing HTML for email. However I cannot get this latest email to work in the Android Gmail app (and **only** in *this* app). We do testing in Email on Acid, which shows no errors for this or any other email clients. I have tried every trick that I know as well as a few new ideas, but no matter what I do the app is still mangling the first few rows in my table. I even tried renaming and re-hosting the images on a wild hunch, but no luck.

I have stripped down the HTML of both this and an older working email to the first couple rows so that they are perfectly matching except for the width and height of the `<td>`'s and the sources of the `<img>`'s. Still, my new email breaks and the old one works just fine. Both emails are being sent from the same service (Constant Contact) and viewed on the same phone (HTC One). You can see a little bit of stretching on the working example, but there are no gaps or blank spaces like there are in the broken one. Note that I removed a big section of the working example in order to get it closer to the dimensions of the broken email. It may look broken but it's not.

If you inspect the source of the two 'short' versions of the email you will see that they are practically the same. Yet as you can see in the screenshots they are being rendered completely differently. As I mentioned before, this is only happening in the Gmail app on Android.

[Broken Full](http://lrxd.com/temp/email-broken.html)

[Broken Short](http://lrxd.com/temp/email-broken-short.html)

[image: Broken Short Screenshot]

[Working Full](http://lrxd.com/temp/email-working.html)

[Working Short](http://lrxd.com/temp/email-working-short.html)

[image: Working Short Screenshot]

I have been working on this all day and haven't gotten any closer to a solution. Please help me if you can!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual I figured this one out not long after posting the question.

The solution, for whatever nutjob reason, was to add a `min-width` attribute to the inline styles of each `<td>` element. The `min-width` matches the `width` and **presto** everything is fine.

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Hello can you tell me how can i send table html in gmail from android.

Comment: What did you set min-width to?